# OpenLayers with react and react-router

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-2, vector, react

I am developing an application that has navigation on various maps, everything works well when a certain map is rendered for the first time, but if you go back to this tab again, the map either does not draw or starts blinking.

Global map component:

```
  export const GlobalMap = (props) => {
  const [map, setMap] = useState();
  const mapElement = useRef();
  const mapRef = useRef();
  mapRef.current = map;


  useEffect( () => {

    const initialMap = new Map({
      target: mapElement.current,
      layers: bLayers,
      view: new View({
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        center: fromLonLat([84.66750819333932, 55.64067604991081]),
        zoom: 8,
      }),
      controls: []
    })

    setMap(initialMap)

    return setMap("")
  },[])
  
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="system">
      </div>

      <div className="contentWrapper">
        <SideBar state={"/Map"}/>
        <div ref={mapElement} className="map-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Local map Component:

```
export const LocalMap = (props) => {
  const [map, setMap] = useState();
  const [baseLayers, setBaseLayers] =  useState(fLayers);
  const mapElement = useRef();
  const mapRef = useRef();
  mapRef.current = map;


  useEffect( () => {

    const initialMap = new Map({
      target: mapElement.current,
      layers: [...baseLayers],
      view: new View({
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        center: fromLonLat([84.66750819333932, 55.64067604991081]),
        zoom: 11,
      }),
      controls: []
    })
    
    setMap(initialMap)

    return setMap("")

  },[])

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="system">
      </div>

      <div className="contentWrapper">
        <SideBar state={"/Map"}/>
        <div ref={mapElement} className="map-local-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Layers:

```
const raster = new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM(),
});

const format = new GeoJSON();

const feature = format.readFeatures(json_255_1, 
  {dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'});

const vector = new VectorLayer({
  source: new VectorSource({
    features: feature,
    }),
  style: {
    'fill-color': 'rgb(23, 73, 212)',
    'stroke-color': 'rgb(23, 73, 212)',
    'stroke-width': 4,
   },
});

const wkt = `MultiLineString ((84.6353696000000042 55.66088890000000333, 84.63664090000000328 55.66087370000000334, 84.65278299999999945 55.66079210000000188, 84.65494750000000579 55.66077239999999904, 84.65812859999999773 55.66074820000000045, 84.66079740000000697 55.66072849999999761, 84.66284129999999664 55.66070890000000304, 84.66468659999999602 55.66070429999999902, 84.66608659999999986 55.66071600000000075, 84.6679239999999993 55.66075730000000021, 84.67361230000000205 55.66089389999999781, 84.68185169999999573 55.66116370000000302, 84.68429159999999456 55.66120430000000141, 84.68762259999999742 55.66123360000000275, 84.68961760000000538 55.66122889999999757, 84.69150329999999371 55.66116300000000194, 84.69346339999999884 55.66105699999999956, 84.6948203000000035 55.66095059999999961, 84.69644739999999672 55.66078819999999894, 84.69866269999999986 55.66048409999999791)) `;
  
    const format2 = new WKT();
  
    const feature2 = format2.readFeature(wkt, {
      dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
      featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
    });

    const vector2 = new VectorLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({
        features: [feature2],
        }),
      style: {
        'fill-color': 'rgb(247, 24, 9)',
        'stroke-color': 'rgb(247, 24, 9)',
        'stroke-width': 8,
      },
    });

export const fLayers = [raster, vector, vector2]
export const bLayers = [raster, vector]
```

And routing map:

```
function App() {

  return (
    <HashRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Authorization/>}/>
            <Route path="/RoadsList" element={<List/>}/>
            <Route path="/Map" element={<GlobalMap/>}/>
            <Route path="/RoadsList/:roadId" element={<Card/>}/>
            <Route path="/RoadsList/edit/:roadId" element={<EditCard/>}/>
            <Route path="/PathList/:roadId" element={<PathList/>}/>
            <Route path="/PathsList/:roadId/:pathId" element={<PathCard/>}/>
            <Route path="/RoadsList/edit/:roadId/:pathId" element={<EditPathCard/>}/>
            <Route path="/Map/:roadId" element={<LocalMap segment={"road"}/>}/>
            <Route path="/Map/:roadId/:pathId/" element={<GlobalMap/>}/>
          </Routes>
    </HashRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

All components work fine for the first few renderers.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
useEffect( () => {

    const initialMap = new Map({
      target: mapElement.current,
      layers: bLayers,
      view: new View({
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        center: fromLonLat([84.66750819333932, 55.64067604991081]),
        zoom: 8,
      }),
      controls: []
    })

    initialMap.updateSize();
    
    console.log("mount");

    return () => initialMap.updateSize();

  },[])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to free the map resources when the component unmounts by setting the map target to null

```js
useEffect( () => {
    const initialMap = new Map({
      target: mapElement.current,
      layers: layersList,
      view: viewConfig
    })
    
    setMap(initialMap)

    return () => initialMap.setTarget(null);
  },[])
```