# OpenLayers map rendering issue in Next.js 13 using TailwindCSS on a page with sticky header and footer

Tags: openlayers, css, react

I am building a web app using Openlayers in Next.js 13 with TailwindCSS. I am encountering a issue/bug with rendering the base map inside a page with a sticky header and footer. The map has scrollbar although the height is fixed to 500px and it also has 2 zoom in/zoom outs button, the latter is shown when the image is scrolled down.  Actually the map should occupy the rest of the page, and when I do that, I have 2 adjacent scrollbars. I think I have a problem with my CSS with OpenLayers. I still yet have to add the layers but I need to fix the base map first.

Here is my repository so you can re-create it: [Openlayers-starter](https://github.com/sonny-uplb/openlayers-starter).

global.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99

}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  min-width: 100vw;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  
}
```

layout.js

```
import Navbar from '@/components/header/Header'
import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import Footer from '@/components/footer/Footer'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Openlayers Starter',
  description: 'Openlayers Starter map',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Navbar />
        {children}
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Basemap.jsx

```
'use client'

import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import TileLayer from "ol/layer/Tile";
import XYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ';
import { fromLonLat } from "ol/proj";
import 'ol/ol.css';

const BaseMap = (props, {children}) => {
    const { center, zoom } = props;
    const mapElement = useRef();

    const baseLayer = new TileLayer (
        { source: new XYZ({
            url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
        })
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        new Map({
          target: mapElement.current,
          layers: [
            baseLayer
          ],
          view: new View({
            center: fromLonLat(center),
            zoom: (zoom)
          })
        });

      }, []);
    
      return (
        <div id="map" ref={mapElement}> {children} </div>
      )
      
}
export default BaseMap;
```

DynamicMap.jsx

```
'use client'

import dynamic from "next/dynamic"

const MapBase = dynamic(
    async() => await import ('./BaseMap'),
    {
        loading: () => <p>Loading Map...</p>,
        ssr: false
    }
)

function DynamicMap() {
    const center = [120.9842, 14.5995];
    const zoom = 7;

    return (
        <MapBase center={center} zoom={zoom}></MapBase>
    )
}


export default DynamicMap;
```

page.js

```
import DynamicMap from "@/components/map_component/DynamicMap";

export default function Home() {

  const center = [120.9842, 14.5995];
    const zoom = 7;

  return (
    <main className="flex-1 overflow-y-auto">
      
      <DynamicMap />
      
    </main>
  )
}
```

**Update:**
I have a previous code using the OpenLayers which have no problems with the rendering of the map.  When I cloned it then tried to install the dependencies (`npm i`), it showed vulnerabilities. [image] So I tried to force fixed it. Then I run my old code and now the same problem occurred. I think this issue is connected to the latest version of postcss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue. This is related to rendering in ReactJS/NextJS. I modified the Basemap code to free the map resources by setting the target to null.

Basemap.jsx

```
useEffect(() => {
        const initialmap = new Map({
          target: mapElement.current,
          layers: [
            baseLayer
          ],
          view: new View({
            center: fromLonLat(center),
            zoom: (zoom)
          })
        });

        initialmap.updateSize();
        return () => initialmap.setTarget(null)

      }, []);
```

I found the answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/447416/openlayers-with-react-and-react-router)